# Artificially reducing CPU speed or number of cores

Tags: c++, macos, juce

I have a pretty beefy development machine that I am using to develop and test my project.  I set up a situation that should load the CPU pretty heavily and checked performance monitor to see that I was using 130% CPU.   I want to know how my program would behave on a machine with fewer cores.  Is there a way to throttle the number of CPUs that the OS will allocate to my program?  Or can I reduce the effective clock speed somehow?

Answer (score 2):

you can run your program inside virtual box. some of them let you change how much resources your os inside virtual box can access like number of cores and threads, amount of memory ...

As far as I know with c++ you can only change form one thread to multi threads and vice versa. So you need to access your OS specific guidelines!

Another way is to run multiple instance of your software all together!